# Display a list of users with avatar filterable with alphabets

Tags: php, functions, customization, filters, users

I'm trying to create a page which should display a list of users with the role "Author" only and exclude all other default and custom roles.

I also want them to be filterable by alphabets, so if I click on "A", or "B", and so on, the users starting with that alphabet should show on the page.

I tried to use wp_list_authors but that's very limited to what I need here. (code below)

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_authors('exclude_admin=1&optioncount=1&show_fullname=1&hide_empty=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

Any idea how this can be done or any plugin for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Be so kind as to show some code that can be improved upon thereafter.

Comment: Updated the question @JohannesPille

Comment: A solution can be built [analyzing](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/author-template.php#L240) the `wp_list_authors` function and [constructing an alphabet array](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+alphabet+array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've got a plugin here which sorts it out.

[amr users wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-users/)